# How to express a condition in a Mongo Pipeline with multiple $and's on the same level

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My problem is that I need to express a condition in a Mongo Aggregation pipeline in the format `((A&B)||(C&D))` which when you write it out in the format that Mongo writes it's boolean expressions in yields `{$or: {$and: {A, B}, $and: {C ,D}}`. The problem with this is that you can't have two elements with the same key in the same array. More specifically I'm using PHP's Mongo plugin so my format actually looks something like

```
array('$or' => 
    array(
        '$and' => array(
            A,
            B
        ),
        '$and' => array(
            C,
            D
        )
    )
);
```

Again, this isn't an array that can exist because the `'$and'` key is being used twice in the same array. Does anyone know of a way to tell mongo how to do this boolean expression? Possibly a way to rewrite it or a different way to translate it into Mongo's boolean structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right syntax. `$or` and `$and` take arrays:

```
((A && B) || (C && D)) ==>
{ "$or" : [{ "$and" : [A, B] }, { "$and" : [C, D] }] }
```